# displacement mapping with WIDTH and HEIGHT or with (WIDTH - 1) and (HEIGHT - 1)?

Tags: opengl, webgl, texture-mapping

I would have a question to http://page.mi.fu-berlin.de/block/htw-lehre/wise2012_2013/bel_und_rend/skripte/szirmay2006.pdf page 4.

Instead WIDTH and HEIGHT in dhdu and dhdv:

```
float2 du=float2(1/WIDTH, 0);
float2 dv=float2(0, 1/HEIGHT);
float dhdu = SCALE/(2/WIDTH) * (tex2D(hMap, uv+du).a - tex2D(hMap, uv-du).a);
float dhdv = SCALE/(2/HEIGHT) * (tex2D(hMap, uv+dv).a - tex2D(hMap, uv-dv).a);
// get model space normal vector
float3 mNormal = normalize(N+t*dhdu+b*dhdv);
```

I use (WIDTH - 1) and (HEIGHT - 1) in dhdu and dhdv in my small javascript testing program:

```
float2 du=float2(1/WIDTH, 0);
float2 dv=float2(0, 1/HEIGHT);
float dhdu = SCALE/(2/(WIDTH - 1)) * (tex2D(hMap, uv+du).a - tex2D(hMap, uv-du).a);
float dhdv = SCALE/(2/(HEIGHT - 1)) * (tex2D(hMap, uv+dv).a - tex2D(hMap, uv-dv).a);
// get model space normal vector
float3 mNormal = normalize(N+t*dhdu+b*dhdv);
```

Else i would get a wrong result. I compare the result with:

```
displacedP0 = displace(p0, normal, height0)
displacedP1 = displace(p1, normal, height1)
displacedP2 = displace(p2, normal, height2)
v0 = displacedP1.minus(displacedP0);
v1 = displacedP2.minus(displacedP0);
displacedSurfaceNormal = v0.cross(v1).normalize();
```

Instead of a texture, i use a simple array for testing.

```
//  v
//    +-------+-------+-------+-------+-------+-------+-------+-------+
//  3 |       |  255  |  170  |       |       |       |       |       |
//    +-------+-------+-------+-------+-------+-------+-------+-------+
//  2 |  255  |h0=170 | h2=85 |   0   |       |       |       |       |
//    +-------+-------+-------+-------+-------+-------+-------+-------+
//  1 |  170  | h1=85 |   0   |   0   |       |       |       |       |
//    +-------+-------+-------+-------+-------+-------+-------+-------+
//  0 |       |   0   |   0   |       |       |       |       |       |
//    +-------+-------+-------+-------+-------+-------+-------+-------+
//        0       1       2       3       4       5       6       7      u
let texture = [];
texture[0] = [];
texture[1] = [];
texture[2] = [];
texture[3] = [];

texture[0][0] = 'x';
texture[1][0] = 0;
texture[2][0] = 0;
texture[3][0] = 'x';

texture[0][1] = 170 / 255;
texture[1][1] = 85 / 255;
texture[2][1] = 0;
texture[3][1] = 0;

texture[0][2] = 255 / 255;
texture[1][2] = 170 / 255;
texture[2][2] = 85 / 255;
texture[3][2] = 0;

texture[0][3] = 'x';
texture[1][3] = 255 / 255;
texture[2][3] = 170 / 255;
texture[3][3] = 'x';
```

Size of the texture:

```
let WIDTH = 8;
let HEIGHT = 4;
```

Here i use (WDITH - 1) and (HEIGHT - 1) to define the u- and v-coordinates of the vertices p0, p1 and p2:

```
let p0 = new Vertex(0, 0, 0);
p0.texture(1 / (WIDTH - 1), 2 / (HEIGHT - 1));

let p1 = new Vertex(0, 0, 1);
p1.texture(1 / (WIDTH - 1), 1 / (HEIGHT - 1));

let p2 = new Vertex(1, 0, 0);
p2.texture(2 / (WIDTH - 1), 2 / (HEIGHT - 1));
```

Is this wrong? Is this the reason, why i always have to program -1?

My texture coordinate system seems to be ok. If u ranges from 0 to 6, then the width is 7. Example see https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb206245%28v=vs.85%29.aspx Also see http://bpeers.com/articles/glpixel/ : "Observe that for a texture of width N, the X coordinate of the center of texel i (i counting from 0..N-1), will be 1/(2.N) + i/N".

[image]

Is this image correct?

Comment: Well, i think, my posted image is not correct. I think, in this case p2 would be: u = 0.1, v = 1/8; p0 u = 0.9, v = 1/8, p1 u = 0.5, v = 7/8 in OpenGL and WebGL.